# How do I get files from GCP VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I currently have a GCP VM where I tried to install something and there was a no memory left error on Ubuntu. I tried opening the SSH again and it is not working.

P.S there is no problem with firewall/connection.

I just want a way to download the files that I had stored in the VM. Is there a way to do this without accessing the Terminal?

Comment: Seems like your GCP VM itself is inaccessible(but not clear from your description). Have you tried to access the it by enabling [interactive access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to the instance's serial console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not able to login through serial console, then the only option left would be to retrieve the data from your OLD VM by creating a new VM.

You can follow the steps below to copy the data from the affected(OLD) VMs disk.

> 1 Create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) from the boot disk of the OLD VM
>
> 2 Create a **new** VM. As a boot disk, you should use a Google public
>   image (important- **do not use** the snapshot you created).
>
> 3 Once that instance is created, try to SSH into it just to test if
>   you are able to access it. There should be no issue at this point with
>   this VM instance, as this is a new instance using a fresh operating
>   system.
>
> 4 In the newly created instance, click on the instance name (in the
>   Console), and then click ‘Edit’ at the top of the page to edit the
>   machine.
>
> 5 In the ‘Additional Disks’ section, click ‘Add item’.
>
> 6 In the ‘Name’ drop-down select ‘Create disk’. In the window that
>   opens add a name for the disk, and in the ‘Source snapshot’ drop-down
>   select the **snapshot you created** in Step 1. Now Click ‘Create’
>
> 7 Click ‘Save’ to save the instances new configuration.
>
> 8 Please SSH into the new instance, and run command $lsblk .  You will
>   be able to see the new disk and partition added (It will most probably
>   be named sdb1 but you should check this and take note).
>
> 9) Please run the following command which will create a mount point at
>   /mnt/newdisk and then mounts the additional disk partition to that
>   mount point. Note- substitute /dev/sdb1 in the below command with the
>   name of the partition if it is different.
>
> $ sudo mkdir /mnt/newdisk | sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb1
>   /mnt/newdisk

The snapshots file system will now be mounted at /mnt/newdisk.

You should now be able to navigate the directories and retrieve any data.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I just got it. Very well explained. Thank you! Can you please tell me how you debugged it ? Have you come across the same situation in the past?

Comment: This is just a workaround to get data from a VM with an issue in disk. In future, it is always a good approach to take the snapshot of a VM 'regularly'. I used the help center article about '[how to resize both persistent boot disks and secondary (non-boot) persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)' for framing the commands.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You saved my life

Comment: Points to note: DiskType should be same. And mind `partition` and not `disk` in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can't connect to the instance you always can take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the disk and then create a copy to mount it in a new instance to recover the data from there.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the OS on the Instance, any changes to the size of disk or Instance did not make any difference. I say size because when I was trying to install something on the VM I got a " No memory left" error after which I ended up trying out a solution on this site that involved using grep to delete some files which were taking too much memory. Now the VM won't open. I realize I have severely over complicated this. I just need the files on the Disk. Is there any way I can get to those if the OS is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

The description and results of your problem do not make sense. However, lets assume that your instance is out of memory and you cannot connect to the instance with SSH.

1. Reboot the instance and try again. Installing software might cause an out of memory issue. Rebooting should correct this.
2. Launch the instance with a larger machine type that has more memory. If this is a memory size problem, this will correct it.
3. Detach the instance's disk and attach to another instance that you can connect to. Mount the file system and copy off the files.

However, if instead your problem is out of disk space, this makes more sense.

Resize the instance disk. In the Google Cloud Console, go to `Compute Engine` -> `Disks`. Click on the disk for your instance. Click `EDIT`. Under `Size` enter a new larger disk size. Now launch your instance. For most operating systems (Ubuntu, Debian, etc.) the OS will automatically resize the root file system. I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/) that covers this in detail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried (1), (2) and (3), it did not make any difference. I even tried resizing the disk and it did not change anything. Could it be possible that the linux version is corrupted?. I  tried creating another instance with a different disk and it seems to be working perfectly fine, so there is no problem in the connection part. Any suggestion on how I can handle this?

Comment: Look at the instance boot from the console serial port. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried creating a new instance with the old disk and it works! I referred to the steps in one of the other suggestions.